# How can I use the compareToIgnoreCase method?

Tags: java, string, methods

How can I use the `compareToIgnoreCase` method of the 'String' class to see if a string is less then or greater then another string? I can't use "`>`" and "`<`".

Comment: Did you take a look at the Javadoc for this method?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: so does it atuomatically return 0 if two string are equal?

Comment: @babaysteps - Didn't you notice the docs - "***Returns:**
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the specified String is greater than, equal to, or less than this String, ignoring case considerations.*"

Comment: Please do researches before asking questions. This is a basic Java question, and the solution is readily available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This routine returns -1, 0, or 1 as values, so you can do something like this:

```
String first;
String second;
... assign first and second

if( first.compareToIgnoreCase(second) < 0) {
    // second is less than first...
} else if first.compareToIgnoreCase(second) == 0) {
    // second is same as first...
} else if first.compareToIgnoreCase(second) > 0) {
    // second is greater than first...
}
```

Comment: The third `if` after the else is redundant.

Comment: Yes, but added for completeness in describing the interface.